# Validate file's extension & size before uploading

Tags: php, laravel, validation, file-upload, laravel-8

I tried to make a file uploader which can should be able to upload mimes viz.: `.jpg, .jpeg, .pdf, .bmp, .png, .doc & .docx`. I also make a request rule given below:

**StoreFileRequest.php**

```
public function rules()
{
    'files.*' => [
        'mimes:jpg,jpeg,pdf,bmp,png,doc,docx',
        'max:20000',
    ],
}
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Http\Requests\Backend\StoreFileRequest;

public function store(StoreFileRequest $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('files'))
    {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            //file Mime type
            $fileMimeType=$file->getClientMimeType();

            //change filename to laravel generated name using above extention
            $filename=$file->hashName();

            //upload file
            $path=$file->storeAs('public/user-existing-health-reports/'.auth()->user()->uuid,$filename);
        }
    }
}
```

**blade**

```
{!! Form::file('files[]',
    array('class' => 'form-control btn btn-file ',
    'accept'=>'.jpg, .jpeg, .pdf, .bmp, .png, .doc, .docx',
    'multiple',
    'required',
    )) !!}
```

Inspite of the validation rule above let's suppose if I try to upload a **`.zip`** & also **`.rar`** file which are around **`1GB`**. The file gets uploaded first which takes quite a very good time and then throws an error after validating.

**My issue:** I need to validate the file extension and size when the user clicks the submit button before it uploads the file to validate via validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation rules and and request data validation against it happens on the server once the Request data is received.

So naturally even if you try to upload 2GB file or a zip file, it will have to reach the server before it gets validated against the validation rules.

You must also implement some validation in the frontend to prevent such issues.

Say for example you can check the mime type and size of the file being uploaded on the frontend (via javascript) and only if it passes the validation here on frontend allow request to be made to the server with the uploaded file.

However never rely only on validation on the frontend. Validation at server level is must.

For example to validate file being uploaded does not exceed 20MB in size

```js
function isValidSize(file) {
    const errors = [];

    const maxUploadSizeInBytes = 20 * 1024 * 1024;

    let valid = true;

    if (file.size > maxUploadSizeInBytes) {

        valid = false;

        let sizeInKb = maxUploadSizeInBytes / 1024;

        let sizeForHumans = sizeInKb < 1024
            ? `${sizeInKb} KB`
            : `${sizeInKb / 1024} MB`;

        this.errors.push(
            `The file exceeds the maximum allowed size of ${sizeForHumans}`
         );
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Function to validate mime type of the file being uploaded against allowed mime types

```js
isValidType(file) {
    const errors = [];

    let acceptedMimes = "jpg,jpeg,png,webp"
        .trim()
        .split(",")
        .map(type => `image/${type}`);

    let valid = true;

    if (!acceptedMimes.includes(file.type)) {
        valid = false;

        let phrase = acceptedMimes.replace(/,/g, " or ");

        this.errors.push(
            `The file type is not allowed. Please upload ${phrase} file.`
        );
     }

     return valid;
}
```

#### Validation on Server (backend) is a MUST

Frontend validation is for better user experience and to save some unnecessary network requests

Comment: I was thinking the same that I might have to use Javascript to validate but is there no other way in Laravel by which we can validate files extension and size without using Javascript at frontend before the files reaches the server?

Comment: or is there anyway by which we can only send file's extension and size first to validate and once server response is true the file gets uploaded then?

Comment: If you don't validate on front end then request with data including large files need to reach the server only after that Laravel can validate against the rules. Validation on front end can save some network requests and provide better experience to the visitors/users

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $errors     = array();
    $maxsize    = 2097152;
    $acceptable = array(
        'application/pdf',
        'image/jpeg',
        'image/jpg',
        'image/gif',
        'image/png'
    );

    if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize) || ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] == 0)) {
        $errors[] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.';
    }

    if((!in_array($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'], $acceptable)) && (!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"]))) {
        $errors[] = 'Invalid file type. Only PDF, JPG, GIF and PNG types are accepted.';
    }

    if(count($errors) === 0) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmpname'], '/store/to/location.file');
    } else {
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            echo '<script>alert("'.$error.'");</script>';
        }

        die(); //Ensure no more processing is done
    }
}
```

use this html code to dont allow to even upload file :

```
<input type="file"
       id="avatar" name="avatar"
       accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

refrence :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: Even in this case the whole .zip file gets upload first and then it validates which again takes same time which is used to upload the 1gb file

Comment: sir check my answer again i ve added a html attribute to dont allow file to even upload

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you use Request and call Request in controller.

```
'files.*' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,pdf|max:1024',
```

do not use comma use OR operator to use file type

PS: 1024 in KB which is 1MB

Comment: the code which I have given is written in request and called in controller as parameter
but whenever I click on upload button after selecting files it firstly upload the whole file **not in storage but it shows its uploading whole file which takes time** and then it validates and throws the error

Comment: then why do not you try my answer. I have tried it which validate user before sending the request. can you provide me whole request code so that I can help you